# Drag and Drop error 1010 part of the time?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have a working drag and drop game, but it's not perfect.  All my movieclips drag and drop to their targets when you are exactly lined up with the target.

However, if you let go of the mouse up when dragging the mc outside of the target zones, it will sometimes, but not always, throw the 1010 term undefined error and will not snap the mc back to its original start x/y coordinates (it just leaves the mc in the spot it was during mouse up).  I ran the debugger and it deals with this line in my drop function:

if (event.currentTarget.dropTarget != null && MovieClip(event.currentTarget.dropTarget.parent).allowed.indexOf(event.currentTarget) >= 0){

FYI, allowed is a set of target arrays since I wanted "zones" for targets and not specific targets for some of the movieclips.

Any ideas?

---

Updated Code Below:

```
if (event.currentTarget.dropTarget != null) {
var mc:MovieClip=event.currentTarget.dropTarget as MovieClip;
if (mc==null) { // typecast fails. Say there's a Sprite below
    reply_txt.textColor = 0xEE1212
    reply_txt.text = "Oops!  Try Again!";
    event.currentTarget.alpha = 1;
    event.currentTarget.x = startX;
    event.currentTarget.y = startY; 
    return; // nothing to do here
}
mc=mc.parent;
if (mc && mc.allowed) { 
    // this MC has "allowed" property not "undefined" - we're in the grid
    // so now we can check indexOf() safely
    if (mc.allowed.indexOf(event.currentTarget)>=0){
        reply_txt.textColor = 0x33BC10
        reply_txt.text = "Good Job!";
        event.currentTarget.alpha = 1;
        event.currentTarget.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, pickUp);
        event.currentTarget.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, dropIt);
        event.currentTarget.buttonMode = false;
        event.currentTarget.x = MovieClip(event.currentTarget.dropTarget.parent).x;
        event.currentTarget.y = MovieClip(event.currentTarget.dropTarget.parent).y;
        stored.push(event.currentTarget);
        startXarray.push(startX);
        startYarray.push(startY);
        counter++;
    }

}
```

}

Comment: My guess would be that something turned null as a result of the end of the drag event.  Null check everything - event.currentTarget, event.currentTarget.dropTarget, and event.currentTarget.dropTarget.parent.

Comment: Ok, I tried tracing and when the error happens, it deals with event.currentTarget.dropTarget.parent.  It returns "root1"?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, when you stopDrag an object, it checks what kind of a DisplayObject is below the cursor, and that one is returned as `dropTarget` property in your event. So, if your object is dropped onto another MC that does not have `allowed` property, your 1010 error is thrown. You need to check this situation in a nested if statement like this:

```
if (event.currentTarget.dropTarget != null) {
    var mc:MovieClip=event.currentTarget.dropTarget as MovieClip;
    if (mc==null) { // typecast fails. Say there's a Sprite below
        returnThisBack();
        return; // nothing to do here
    }
    mc=mc.parent;
    if (mc && mc.allowed) { 
        // this MC has "allowed" property not "undefined" - we're in the grid
        // so now we can check indexOf() safely
        if (mc.allowed.indexOf(event.currentTarget)>=0)  snapThisToGrid();
    } else returnThisBack();
} else returnThisBack();
```

Comment: I haven't really used nested statements before.  I tried updating my code based on your example, but it only runs through the first function of returning the mc to its starting position.  It no longer wants to snap to any of the targets.  I've posted my code above (I removed the last two else conditions for testing).

Comment: The other part that I find strange is that when the error is thrown (under my original code), there is no movieclip in that space on the stage, so why would it be applying a dropTarget to a non-existent movieclip?

Comment: One more thing.  I mentioned previously that when adopting your code to mine, I could no longer drop the movieclips to the targets and they would always snap back to their starting position.  However, if I change the "MovieClip" to "DisplayObject" in the line "var mc:MovieClip=event.currentTarget.dropTarget as MovieClip;", then I can get the movieclip to drop to the target zone (but I still get the 1010 error).

Comment: You can, for example, make all your DisplayObjects that make your grid a certain type, say `GridElement` a descendant from wherever you need, be it MovieClip or something else. Then, use that type to check if your `dropTarget` is valid, and if yes, then you are certain your drag is within the grid, thus you can skip all other checks except for `indexOf()`.

Comment: Won't I still be facing the same problem of the property "allowed" checking against all of the same data type even if I do this?

Comment: You should not, because you can add this property into your class, then initialize it somewhere within grid creation code or the constructor. Also after you would make such a typecast, the compiler will catch bugs with absent/mistyped properties, which is not the case with dynamic objects such as `MovieClip`.